# Laptop won't boot after alcohol spill

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, post

So I just had a minor spill and let everything dry out. Now when I try to boot my laptop, I get one or two beeps on the BIOS splash screen before the laptop shuts down. I can't get to the post screen so I'm not sure what the error is.

I'm sure that the beeps aren't finishing either so I can't accurately determine the symptoms.

Attempted boot without HDD or battery.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably it is motherboard and you cannot fix it yourself.

Comment: odd as it may seem, what kinda alchol?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Isopropyl, 70% rubbing alcohol.

Comment: that shouldn't harm it too much in theory.

Comment: "Isopropyl, 70% rubbing alcohol" that is the problem, it wanted rum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By finding the exact model of your motherboard you can find its user manual and this way you can find our exactly what the one or two beeps means. The count of beeps is very important, it is the error message.

Comment: http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-74890 has the beep symptoms. The problem is that it shuts down before all the beeps can finish. I'm starting to suspect that there's a power issue since the battery is practically useless now. The AC adapter is REQUIRED for the laptop to even start (and die in 10sec).